# Add hidden data to text file

Tags: text, hidden

Is there anyway to add a hidden data to the text file.

For example, in the below text - 
*Add **hidden** text to file.*
I want the text file to only display -
*Add text to file.*
But I will still have the hidden word in the document, which I can look at as and when needed.

Comment: what is the technologies you using to achieve this ?

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding you question right, I am using simple .txt files, however I am open to any possible technology which would help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to my question

http://techmeasy.blogspot.com/2013/05/hide-data-text-file-without-software.html